# QML - main window position on start (screen center)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

How I can do following: I’d like show my main window on start on the center screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [`setGeometry`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) on your top-level widget before you show it. The easiest way I can think of to work out what geometry you need is via [`QDesktopWidget`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html). Try the example below (create a `QPushButton`, press it while moving the widget around various screens) and you'll see what I mean:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{   
  ui->setupUi(this);
  connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(ButtonPressed()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::ButtonPressed()
{
  qDebug() << QApplication::desktop()->screenCount();
  qDebug() << QApplication::desktop()->screenNumber();
  qDebug() << QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(this);
}
```

Should be reasonably simple from there to come up with a generic version that works out a user's center screen (if it exists).

Answer (score 30):

If using QtQuick, it's possible to do that:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 480
    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Commenting this to use properties instead of setters
        //setX(Screen.width / 2 - width / 2);
        //setY(Screen.height / 2 - height / 2);
        x = Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
        y = Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
    }
}
```

Comment: On the usability, this's the best answer for me. Upvoted

Comment: As mention in [the comments of the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970766/qml-main-window-position-on-start-screen-center#comment87487953_26424028), one should rather use the `screen` property instead of the `Screen` singleton. Citing the documentation of the `Screen` type: "Note that the Screen type is not valid at Component.onCompleted, because the Item or Window has not been displayed on a screen by this time."

Answer (score 24):

Dielson's answer is much better, especially since widgets weren't mentioned... anyway, here's an even simpler version of his answer:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
    y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
    width: 320
    height: 480
}
```

---

As mentioned by Alexander, this binding can result in weird resizing behaviour. Because of that, it's better to use Dielson's answer. The only thing I'd mention is that it's not common to use setters in QML; some systems (I believe they're called property interceptors) even rely on properties being set to perform animations, for example. So the more common approach is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: {
        x = Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
        y = Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
    }
}
```

Comment: For `ApplicationWindow` there is a `screen` property.

Comment: Either people cannot see that right away or they did not try? BTW, what about multi-monitor situation? The only correct way would be using `screen` property of `Window` then. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#screen-prop

Comment: Not sure. It might have worked (resized without issues) back in 2014.

Comment: Absolutely sure and checked just yesterday on Ubuntu with 2 monitors of different dimensions. Depending on which monitor is main and has index 0 or Screen there is a bug of incorrect centering of the Window.

Comment: I said I'm not sure - I speak for myself. It's good that you're checking this stuff out, but I'm not accounting for multi-monitor setups in my answer, so feel free to provide your own.

Comment: Scratch that. Providing my reply as well.

Answer (score 3):

After examining both replies and actually debugging the code with Qt 5.9.1 it shows more than one issue with original replies:

1. Cannot bind [x, y] to [width, height] unless we want to see strange effects with resizing.
2. Even though [x, y] change in `Component.onCompleted` seems to be logical it does not work as expected with 2 monitors of different DPI (as on systems I currently develop on).
3. Need to use `Window.screen` instead of `Screen` singleton type. That way we get actual screen matching the window on.
4. To completely untie [x, y] from dynamic values but the actual window screen at the moment of the initial window showing we now use `onScreenChanged` which is a handler for the `screen` property change.

This solution is more complete and uses [Window.screen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#screen-prop) property:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    property bool screenInit: false

    title: qsTr("App Window Positioning")
    visible: true

    height: Theme.windowHeight // initial
    width: Theme.windowWidth   // initial

    Connections {
        target: window
        onScreenChanged: if (!screenInit) {
            // we have actual screen delivered here for the time when app starts
            screenInit = true
            window.x = screen.width / 2 - Theme.windowWidth / 2
            window.y = screen.height / 2 - Theme.windowHeight / 2
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If so I used `ApplicationWindow` type which is derived from `Window` and it should be consistent with `Window` positioning behavior.

Comment: I tested this with Qt 5.15 on macOS but the `onScreenChanged` is not called when the window is initially shown. Only when the window is moved to another screen. Could be this changed somewhen..

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are missing to take the screen positioning into account potentially causing the window to show up on the wrong screen. Maybe this used to work in previous version of Qt but it doesn't seem work with recent Qt versions anymore.

The following solution works for me with a multi-screen with different DPI setup (requires Qt 5.9 or later; tested with Qt 5.15 on macOS):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.9

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: {
        root.x = root.screen.virtualX + root.screen.width / 2 - root.width / 2;
        root.y = root.screen.virtualY + root.screen.height / 2 - root.height / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. Also works on windows 11 with Qt 6.4.2 :)

Comment: Verified works and doesn't interfere with Android on 6.6.1

Answer (score 1):

[Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52488189) is almost good enough. However, on KDE I observe the following behaviour: the window is first opened on Monitor 1 and then is immediately moved to Monitor 2. In this situation, the referenced answer always forces the window to Monitor 1.

Since trying to detect this behaviour would probably require quite a bit of code, I just went for a simple solution by using a Timer:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: window

  visible: true
  height: 320
  width: 480

  function setCoordinates() {
    x += screen.width / 2 - width / 2
    y += screen.height / 2 - height / 2
  }

  Timer {
    id: timer
    running: true
    repeat: false
    interval: 10
    onTriggered: {
      window.setCoordinates();
    }
  }
}
```

This sets the window's coordinates after waiting for 10ms (hopefully in that time the DE has done its job).