# QML Center window in primary screen

Tags: linux, qt, qml

I want to put my qml window at center of my primary screen. and as figure shown I have 3 monitor which my primary screen is the middle one.

The problem is x and y properties in qml window are not relative to screen but global. So I cannot use what suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970766/qml-main-window-position-on-start-screen-center) which is result in window apear on both none primary screen and non center.

I'm looking into some variable contains each screen position in x and y, although just do centering is much more better :)

[image: My Monitor Configuration]

Comment: If  your main screen is the central one you could use the Screen.desktopAvailableWidth / 2 as a center.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution has two weakness.
first, as you seen my right monitor resolution is not the same as the left, second, it only solve the problem in x direction not y. considering each monitor position

Comment: Well you can detect all your screens size from c++ with                          QWidget *QDesktopWidget::screen(int screen = -1)     Then with the coord x you will know in what window you are so you can center the panel in that particular screen using his concret height

Comment: yes that's some good answer, I also used xrender tool to get offset https://paste.kde.org/pgcnzif2f. look like there isn't better solution out there